# Gaussians as good kernels

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

**Theorem.** If $\delta>0$ and 
$$K_{\delta}(x) = \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{- \pi \frac{x^2}{\delta}},$$
then
$$\widehat{K_{\delta}}(\xi) = e^{- \pi \delta \xi^2}.$$
**Proof.**
I started the proof in a very expected way.
$$\widehat{K_{\delta}}(\xi) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{- \pi \frac{x^2}{\delta}} e^{-2 \pi ix \xi} \mbox{d}x. \tag{1}$$
Unfortunately I don't know how to evaluate $(1)$. I think using the following equality might help
$$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \pi x} \mbox{d}x =1$$
but I don't know how to use it. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is equal to
$$
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{- \pi \frac{x^2}{\delta}} e^{-2 \pi ix \xi}dx = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- \pi x^2} e^{-2 \pi i\sqrt{\delta} x \xi}dx= e^{-\pi\delta\xi^2}\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- \pi (x+i\sqrt{\delta}\xi)^2} dx.
$$
Note that
$$
\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{- \pi (x+i\sqrt{\delta}\xi)^2} dx=\int_{\Im(z)=\sqrt{\delta}\xi}e^{- \pi z^2} dz.
$$ By Cauchy's integral theorem, we can show that
$$
\int_{\Im(z)=\sqrt{\delta}\xi}e^{- \pi z^2} dz =\int_{\Im(z)=0}e^{- \pi z^2} dz=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- \pi z^2} dz=1.
$$

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the second line? I can't see how did you get $\Im{z}$ in the integration limit.

Comment: The left hand side is just the line integral of $z\mapsto e^{-\pi z^2}$ over $\Im(z) = \sqrt{\delta}\xi$ parametrized by $\gamma(t) = t+i\sqrt{\delta}\xi, \quad -\infty <t<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help and knowledge!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)